# Sending created SQLite db to xamarin application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I am working on a mobile Xamarin application that uses sqlite-net-pcl to store static and dynamic data.

**Right Now**

The data (static and dynamic) are originated from a database that is queried by an ASP.net web server.

Until now I am sending a separate request for each batch of data. The data are transferred as JSON files and after being deserialized inside the application they are stored to the SQLite database.

For that I am using a shared library of objects. The sqlite-net-pcl has convenient methods to transform the objects to tables and query them with Linq-like functions without losing the object oriented scope of the code.

The shared code classes look like:

```
[Table("Drivers")]
public class Driver
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table("Cars")]
public class Car
{
     public string PlateNum { get; set; }

     [Ignore]
     public Driver Driver { get; set; }

     public int _DriverId;

     public int DriverId 
     { 
         get
         {
             return Driver?.Id ?? _DriverId;
         }
         set
         {
             _DriverId = value;
         }
     }
}
```

The Xamarin Database code looks like this:

```
public DataBase(string dbpath)
{
    database = new SQLiteConnection(dbpath);

    database.CreateTable<Driver>();
    database.CreateTable<Car>();
}
```

The Web server controller looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Cars/GetAll")]
public List<Car> GetCars()
{
     List<Car> Cars = new List<Car>();

     //db connection filling the List

     return Cars;
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("Drivers/GetAll")]
public List<Driver> GetDrivers()
{
     List<Driver> Drivers = new List<Driver>();

     //db connection filling the List

     return Drivers;
}
```

With that I am able to receive the lists to the Xamarin application and store them as simple as that:

```
foreach (Car car in Cars)
{
    database.InsertOrReplace(car);
}

foreach (Driver driver in Drivers)
{
    database.InsertOrReplace(driver);
}
```

**The Issue**

Like Driver and Car I am using about 15 other classes that in total they can be over 25mb in separate JSON files (*which is **not** the real issue*), or about a million unique table rows (*which is the real issue*).

**For Time**

For optimization's sake I have decided to go a questionable route (that obviously is not working at the moment) of assembling the db at the web server and then sending the file to the application. This is almost working except for the fact that I haven't found a way to objectify the available SQLite libraries that work on ASP.net. sqlite-net-pcl is not working at all same with Microsoft.Data.SQLite, System.Data.SQLite is working and its file is compatible with the application's version.

**The Question**

Is there any clean way to use pcl-like tools to create/insert tables and data in the web server file?
Is there any other better solution for time optimization?

Thank you for you time

Comment: compress the sqlite data file on the server and send the entire file to the client.  I've done this before and it works.

Comment: This works indeed but the issue is that I haven't found a way to use something like ``database.CreateTable<object>()`` and/or ``database.InsertOrReplace(object)`` on the webserver

Comment: if that is your actual problem, then you did not state it very clearly in either your question or it's title.  Is there a reason you haven't tried using the same sqlite-net package on the server that you use on the client?

Comment: I tried but it is not compatible with the asp.net application

Comment: try using an older version, or upgrade your asp.net project to .net core

Comment: Unfortunately , it doesn't work with the specific project, thanks for your suggestion though.